# Is there any performance penalty with a Debug.WriteLine(ex); statement when a release version of my application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using this construct:

```
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    db2.Rollback();
    throw;
 }
```

When a release version of the application is created will anything happen in other words will that debug information get logged anywhere, will there be any performance penalty or will it just be ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated for Roslyn compiler:

`Debug.WriteLine` is dependent upon if there is a compiler symbol of `DEBUG` defined and whether "Optimization" is turned on. *Typically* a Release configuration does not have a `DEBUG` compiler symbol defined and optimizations set to  `True`.

#### Code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
Debug.WriteLine("Hello World!");
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

#### `Debug` symbol not defined, Optimization : `False`

```
IL_0000:  ldstr      "Hello World!"
IL_0005:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_000b:  nop
IL_000a:  ldstr      "Hello World!"
IL_000f:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

But with optimizations true on, the `NOP` is stripped.

#### `Debug` symbol not defined, Optimization : `True`

```
IL_0000:  ldstr      "Hello World!"
IL_0005:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_000a:  ldstr      "Hello World!"
IL_000f:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

#### `Debug` symbol defined, Optimization : `False`:

```
IL_0001:  ldstr      "Hello World!"
IL_0006:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
IL_000b:  nop
IL_000c:  ldstr      "Hello World!"
IL_0011:  call       void [System]System.Diagnostics.Debug::WriteLine(string)
IL_0016:  nop
IL_0017:  ldstr      "Hello World!"
IL_001c:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it is completely ignored. When you run the App in release, no debug messages are displayed in the console.

Answer (score 1):

When compiling release compiler removes all unnecessary code (comments/debug/line breaks).

Answer (score 1):

From the Microsoft [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug(v=vs.110).aspx) on `Debug`:

> If you use methods in the Debug class to print debugging information
>   and check your logic with assertions, you can make your code more
>   robust without impacting the performance and code size of your
>   shipping product.

Further reading learns that calls to `Debug` are removed when you create a release build. So, there is no penalty performance-wise when including these kinds of calls.

Answer (score 1):

It is ignored when app launched in release mode, so there is no performance issue, in release mode Trace.Debuge is choice